# why method with Flowable<List> of Room DAO never completes?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

Fetching data from  DB  , Room DAO has a method that returns a Flowable userDao.getInfo(), this Flowable will never completes, I tested adding doOnNext() it emits 5 times (DB contains 5 items) but complete is never called, but I need as I have toList(),what could be the alternative for this

```
return userDatas()
    .flatMapIterable(items -> items)
    .flatMap(userData -> userDao.getInfo(userData.getId())
        .map(user -> user.toStoreModel(...)//added doOnNext()-works 5 times and doOnComplete()doesn't work
  .doOnNext(userData -> Log.i("test",""+userData))
    .doOnComplete(() -> Log.i("test","complete"))
        .toList()
        .map(UserModel::fromUserModels)
        .toFlowable();


@Query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = :id") 
Flowable<...> getInfo(Long Id);

  public Flowable<List<UserStore>> userDatas() {
return userDao.allUserDatas()
    .take(1)//added complete and next works 
    .filter(userDatas -> !userDatas.isEmpty())
    .switchIfEmpty(userIds()
        .doOnNext(userDatas -> userDao.insert(userDatas)));

 }
```

I have tested and even when I'm replacing userDatas() only with userDao.allUserDatas() (I'm sure it exists in DB) it gives the same results

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to have called complete method you can use take(1).but in that case you could not listener further DB changes

Answer (score 3):

Everything is ok with your code ,it would never complete
Db Flowables are observable ,so they keep listening if database changes, so it never completes.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you should fix `userDao` so that it completes normally. If that is not possible for some reason, you can time it out and map error to empty, forcing completion like so:

```
userDao.getInfo(userData.getId())
   .timeout(1, TimeUnit.SECOND)
   .onErrorResumeNext(Observable.empty())
```

Comment: what you mean by fixing?, as I don't have any idea that the data that I'm storing is wrong,here my codes for fetching and I have posted also the code when I need to fetch the list not one single userInfo ,it works for sure but I have issues when fetching one item

@hgrey


  @Query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = :id")
  Flowable<...> getInfo(Long Id);

  @Query("SELECT * FROM store WHERE id IN (:ids)")
  Flowable<List<...>> userInfoWithIds(List<Long> ids);

Comment: By fixing I mean that `userDao` should call `onComplete`. If you can amend your question with `userDao.getInfo` code then more concrete answer can be given.

Comment: can you also please add `userDatas()` code? And can you try adding `materialize()` before `toList` and log everything in `doOnNext`.

Comment: I have updated and added materialize() but it causes issues after toList() in map() saying bad return type in reference could not covert ....

Comment: ok. you would have to map back from notification, or just additionally add `doOnError`  and check if anything gets logged

Comment: I added doOnError() after flatMap() and map() (before toList()) but it didn't call , neither doOnError()  nor doOnComplete() are not called ,but doOnNext works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151692/discussion-between-hgrey-and-a-a-i-a).